# How to integrate libraries from cygwin into eclpise for c/c++

Tags: c, eclipse, exif, libexif

I am trying to integrate the libexif library into a project of mine. I used the cygwin application to install the libexif-doc library.
I'm looking for the static library and header files but can't find them within the cygwin installation folder. Where does cygwin safe the library files? How can I tell eclipse how to deal with the library and header files properly?

I tried installing cygwin and looked through cygwins directory for a static .a library and .h files connected to libexif, without success.